# what does it mean when it says endless loop

Tags: python, loops

I am I am trying to run this code in Python and nothing happens. I am looking at this site, and about the 56 minute mark, he has the same code, but he is PROMPTED to enter a number, where as I am not. he also mentions a "play" ? button was that a slip or is that different than the run button.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw&t=12017s

```
num1=input("enter 1st number")
num2-input("enter 2nd number")
result=num1+num2
print(result)
```

I will ask the same question as before. I assume I am in some kind of an endless loop because I let it run, and a half hour later I try exiting out, and it says that the "process is still running". How can that be? PS, I am 59 and just learning python on my own, so go easy on me. :-) thank you for response.

Comment: By "play", he means to run the python code. Also, ```num2=input("enter 2nd number")```, check out for the minus instead of ```=```

Answer (score 1):

Update equal to sign for num2

```py
num1=input("enter 1st number")
num2=input("enter 2nd number")
result=num1+num2
print(result)
```

I have tested this code and its working.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**solution 1:**
replace your code snippet with the equal symbol(=) instead of a hyphen(-)

```
num1=input("enter 1st number")
num2=input("enter 2nd number")
result=num1+num2
print(result)
```

**Solution 2:**
By default input type is a string.
ex:

```
num1=input("enter 1st number")
type(num1)
<class 'str'>
```

now you convert into str to int. then your code snippet was:

```
num1 = int(input("enter 1st number"))
num2 = int(input("enter 2nd number"))
result = num1 + num2
print(result)
```

Comment: thanks for comments.  I tried doing all suggestions.  Man.. this is humbling.  I just keep getting the same error.  I also do not understand why it keeps referring to "main" when I run something else.  I ran again this morning, and got the same error, as if it has been running for hours.  I am just going to hang it up here,  I suppose.. and concentrate on SAS.  thanks again

Comment: your welcome. please accept my answer. resource: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow